# Issues when getting and posting Django formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I'm having two issues when I use a Django formset derived from models in my project:

1. **GET. No `required` fields**. My template doesn't add `required` to `<input>` tags even with model fields that are non-optional -- like the `file` field in my `QualificationDocument` model below. I expect to see `required` in its form field, but don't.

   `<input type="file" name="documents-0-file" id="id_documents-0-file">`

Without these `required` tags, validation can't happen on the client side.

2. **POST. Odd validation errors on the server side.** When I submit this formset, it ends up with errors. Here's what I get in the view function that processes the request.POST:

   `formset.errors = [{'file': ['This field is required.']}]`

As you can see, there's data in the request.POST for that field, but I still get the error:

```
request.POST =  <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['asfdasdfasdfasdfQ8pasdafasdf5x33LRmpa7FdY4vKobTtwkWlEOIw3'], 'documents-TOTAL_FORMS': ['1'], 'documents-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'documents-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'documents-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'documents-0-id': [''], 'documents-0-file': ['testpic.jpg'], 'documents-0-name': ['Test name'], 'documents-0-description': ['Test description']}>
```

Here are the relevant models in my models.py:

```
class Qualification(Data):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_approved = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class QualificationDocument(models.Model):
    qualification = models.ForeignKey(Qualification, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='documents')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='qualification_docs/%Y/%m')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is from my views.py:

```
    q = Qualification.objects.get(id=q_id)
    QualificationDocumentFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(Qualification, QualificationDocument,
        fields=('file', 'name', 'description'),
        widgets={
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}),
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Description'}) },
        extra=1)
    if request.POST:
        formset = QualificationDocumentFormSet(request.POST, instance=q)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
    else:
        formset = QualificationDocumentFormSet(instance=q)
    # Render formset in Django template here
```

This is from the template file:

```
<form id='upload-form-{{ q.id }}' method="post" action="{% url 'submit_and_refresh' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <div id="form_set">
        {% for f in formset.forms %}
            {{ f.non_field_errors }}
            {{ f.errors }}
            <div class="doc-form">
                <div class="new-qual-doc-params">
                    {{ f.id }}
                    {{ f.file }}
                    {{ f.name }}
                    {{ f.description }}
                </div>
                <div class="new-qual-doc-delete">
                    {{ f.DELETE }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Save</button>
</form>
```

To summarize, I'd like the forms of my formset to validate on the client side -- for which I need those missing `required` tags in the form fields -- and for the submit to work properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't the whole solution, but a couple of key things I missed:

1. The enctype on the form.

   `<form id='upload-form-{{ q.id }}' method="post" action="{% url 'submit_and_refresh' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
2. Including request.FILES in formset processing.

   `formset = QualificationDocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=q)`

That took care of Issue 2. And Issue 1 became a non-issue when I incorporated **jquery.formset.js** to handle adding and removing forms from the formset.